# Нужна помощь с реализацией алгоритма Minimax для игры Connect Four. c#

Tags: c#

Код самой игры без интерфейса, довольно объемный. Пытался реализовать несколько вариантов алгоритма, ничего не выходит.
Игра - четыре в ряд. Суть игры - собрать 4 элемента в ряд на доске(диагонали тоже считаются).
Основной метод поиска хода для бота - minimax. Данный метод ищет столбец(col) - самый рациональный для бота ход. В моей реализации он выдает абсолютно рандомные значения, не зависящие от ситуации на доске.
ДЕЛАЛ ПО ВИДЕО! Там на питоне. Тайминг (50:42) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMLtza3CZFM&t=4473s

```
        private void Shift(int[,] copyBoard, int x,int y, int CurrPlayer) // ход
        {
            copyBoard[x, y] = CurrPlayer;
        }

       

        private bool isPossible(int[,] copyBoard, int x)  // проверка на возможность хода
        {
            if (copyBoard[x, 0] != 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        public int Winner(int[,] b)  // проверка на победу
        { 
            for (int x = size - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                for (int y = size - 1; y >= 0; y--)
                {
                    if (b[x, y] != 0 &&
                        (VerticalConnectFour(b, x, y) || HorizontalConnectFour(b, x, y) || ForwardDiagonalConnectFour(b, x, y) || BackwardDiagonalConnectFour(b, x, y)))
                        return b[x, y];
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        private bool VerticalConnectFour(int[,] _board, int x, int y) // вертикальная проверка
        {
            if (_board[x, y] == 0)
                return false;
            int count = 1;
            int rowCursor = x - 1;
            while (rowCursor >= 0 && _board[rowCursor, y] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                rowCursor--;
            }
            rowCursor = x + 1;
            while (rowCursor < size && _board[rowCursor, y] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                rowCursor++;
            }
            if (count < 4)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private bool HorizontalConnectFour(int[,] _board,int x, int y) // горизонтальная проверка
        {
            if (_board[x, y] == 0)
                return false;
            int count = 1;
            int yPtr = y - 1;
            while (yPtr >= 0 && _board[x, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                yPtr--;
            }
            yPtr = y + 1;
            while (yPtr < size && _board[x, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                yPtr++;
            }
            if (count < 4)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private bool ForwardDiagonalConnectFour(int[,] _board, int x, int y) // по диагонали
        {
            if (_board[x, y] == 0)
                return false;
            int count = 1;
            int xPtr = x - 1;
            int yPtr = y + 1;
            while (xPtr >= 0 && yPtr < size && _board[xPtr, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                xPtr--;
                yPtr++;
            }
            xPtr = x + 1;
            yPtr = y - 1;
            while (xPtr < size && yPtr >= 0 && _board[xPtr, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                xPtr++;
                yPtr--;
            }
            if (count < 4)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private bool BackwardDiagonalConnectFour(int[,] _board, int x, int y) // по диагонали в обратную сторону
        {
            if (_board[x, y] == 0)
                return false;
            int count = 1;
            int xPtr = x + 1;
            int yPtr = y + 1;
            while (xPtr < size && yPtr < size && _board[xPtr, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                xPtr++;
                yPtr++;
            }
            xPtr = x - 1;
            yPtr = y - 1;
            while (xPtr >= 0 && yPtr >= 0 && _board[xPtr, yPtr] == _board[x, y])
            {
                count++;
                xPtr--;
                yPtr--;
            }
            if (count < 4)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        

        private bool isFull(int[,] b) // проверка на заполнение доски
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (b[i, j] == 0)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private List<int> row_arr(int[,] b, int r)  // создает список из определенной строки
        {
            List<int> arr = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                arr.Add(b[i, r]);
            }
            return arr;
        }

        private List<int> col_arr(int[,] b, int r) // создает список из определенного столбца
        {
            List<int> arr = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                arr.Add(b[r, i]);
            }
            return arr;
        }

        private int ListCheck(List<int> l, int c) // проверка колонки/ столбца на заполненность фишками определенного игрока(c)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
            {
                if (l[i] == c)
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        private List<int> TakeFour(List<int> l, int idx) // берет четыре элемента из строки/ столбца от определенного индекса
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                a.Add(l[i + idx]);
            }
            return a;
        }

        private int CompScore(List<int> four, int curr)
        {
            int score = 0;

            if (ListCheck(four, curr) == 4)
                score += 100;
            else if (ListCheck(four, curr) == 3 && ListCheck(four, 0) == 1)
                score += 10;
            else if (ListCheck(four, curr) == 2 && ListCheck(four, 0) == 2)
                score += 5;

            if (ListCheck(four, SwitchPlayer(curr)) == 3 && ListCheck(four, 0) == 1)
                score -= 80;

            return score;
        }
        private int score_position(int[,] b, int curr)  // вычисляет важность определенной позиции(для алгоритма)
        {
            int score = 0;
            List<int> center = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                center.Add(b[size / 2, i]);
            }
            int center_count = ListCheck(center, curr);
            score += center_count * 6;
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                List<int> row = row_arr(b, i);
                for (int j = 0; j < size - 3; j++)
                {
                    List<int> four = TakeFour(row, j);
                    score += CompScore(four, curr);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                List<int> col = col_arr(b, i);
                for (int j = 0; j < size - 3; j++)
                {
                    List<int> four = TakeFour(col, j);
                    score += CompScore(four, curr);
                }
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < size - 3; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < size - 3; r++)
                {
                    List<int> four = new List<int>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        four.Add(b[c + i, r + i]);
                    }
                    score += CompScore(four, curr);
                }
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < size - 3; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < size - 3; r++)
                {
                    List<int> four = new List<int>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        four.Add(b[c + i, r + 3 - i]);
                    }
                    score += CompScore(four, curr);
                }
            }
            return score;
        }

        private bool is_terminal(int[,] b) // проверка на победу/заполненность
        {
            if (Winner(b) != 0 || isFull(b))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public int GetAIMove(int curr)  // вспомогательный метод для получения хода
        {
            int[,] cop = (int[,])board.Clone();
            int sc = minimax(cop, 4, true, curr);
            return col;
        }

        private List<int> get_valid_locations(int[,] copyBoard) // получает возможные для хода столбцы
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (isPossible(copyBoard, i))
                    a.Add(i);
            }
            return a;
        }

        private int get_next_open_row(int[,] copyBoard, int x) // ищет свободную ячейку в столбце x.
        {
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (copyBoard[x, i] == 0)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        private int minimax(int[,] copyBoard, int depth, bool maximazing, int curr) // сам алгоритм
        {
            List<int> validloc = get_valid_locations(copyBoard);
            int a = Winner(copyBoard);
            if (depth == 0 || is_terminal(copyBoard))
            {
                if (is_terminal(copyBoard))
                {
                    if (a == curr)
                        return 10000000;
                    else if (a == SwitchPlayer(curr))
                        return -10000000;
                    else
                        return  0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int sc = score_position(copyBoard, curr);
                    return sc;
                }
            }
            if (maximazing)
            {
                int val = -int.MaxValue;
                int new_score = val;
                foreach(int c in validloc)
                { 
                    int r = get_next_open_row(copyBoard, c);
                    int[,] cop = (int[,])copyBoard.Clone();
                    Shift(cop, c, r, curr);
                    new_score = minimax(cop, depth - 1, false, SwitchPlayer(curr));
                    if (new_score > val)
                    {
                        val = new_score;
                        col = c;
                    }
                }
                return new_score;
            }
            else
            {
                int val = int.MaxValue;
                int new_score = val;
                foreach (int c in validloc)
                {
                    int r = get_next_open_row(copyBoard, c);
                    int[,] cop = (int[,])copyBoard.Clone();
                    cop[c, r] = curr;
                    new_score = minimax(cop, depth - 1, true, SwitchPlayer(curr));
                    if (new_score > val)
                    {
                        val = new_score;
                        col = c;
                    }
                }
                return new_score;
            }
        }

        
        private int SwitchPlayer(int curr)  // меняем игрока
        {
            return curr == 2 ? 1 : 2;
        }
```

Comment: Это так не работает. Вы не получите ответ, если просто кинули пару слов и полотно кода (даже без комментариев, еще и часть кода закомментировано) - в чем полезность этого? Вам придется подробней рассказать о вашей игре, вашей проблеме, что конкретно не работает и предоставить **минимальный** код для понимания проблемы. См [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Алгоритмические ошибки отлавливаются при помощи [отладки кода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2017). Выполняйте код пошагово, смотрите в процессе выполнения значения переменных, сравнивайте со своими ожиданиями.

Comment: Вам надо изучить модульное тестирование и отладку. Такие вещи лучше писать через тестирование.